# Switch Worksheet Names without Updating References to those Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

My file has two identical Worksheets for users to input two different sets of assumption variables, called "InputA" and "InputB".  I want to quickly switch which Input sheet is feeding into the other sheets of the model.

Using Find and Replace took over 5 minutes, and there were over 350,000 references to "InputA".

I tried the following macro, which takes an instant to run, but unfortunately also changes all references in the workbook, effectively keeping everything referenced to the original input sheet.

```
Sheets("InputA").Name = "temp"
Sheets("InputB").Name = "InputA"
Sheets("temp").Name = "InputB"
```

Is there a way to execute the macro but prevent any references to worksheets from changing to the new sheet name, basically freezing everything except the sheet name change?  Or perhaps any other solution that will work quickly?  I don't want to go through 350,000 instances and rewrite using INDIRECT(), as that is the only other solution I've seen, because my references are complex and nested and that will take an age.

Thanks.

Comment: What if you fill with formulas for both sheets and use a conditional to reference one or another? `=IF(A1="InputB",FORMULA FOR INPUTB,FORMULA FOR INPUTA)`

Comment: Using `INDIRECT` would also slow down your entire workbook immensely, since it's a volatile function (meaning it's calculated at every change). @Damian's approach sounds reasonable, instead of going through 350.000 formulas by hand you can use a macro to adjust all the formulas for you.

Comment: I think rewriting the formulas is unrealistic.  File is already around 25MB.  Also, many of these formulas are nested 5 or 6 layers deep in IF statements.  I can't imagine doubling the length of all 350,000 of these formulas.  And then what if a 3rd Input tab is needed later?  I have to think there is a VBA solution...some way to execute a name change to the sheet so that all of those formulas think they are going to the same Input tab, but in fact they are referencing the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your 2 Input-Sheets have the same structure, I would suggest the following:

1. Create a named range on Workbook-level, name it for example `InputData`. This range should contain all data from `InputA`.
2. Create a helper-sheet and name it `Input` - you can later set it to hidden.
3. Mark the range in the new sheet that is exactly the size of the `Input-Data`-Range and enter the formula `=InputData` as *Array*-formula. You can do so by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The formula should have curly brackets and the sheet should now display the data of `InputA`.
4. Change all you formulas to refer to the helper Sheet `Input` instead of `InputA`.
5. Create a macro:

   ```
   Sub switchInput()

       Const sheetAName = "InputA"
       Const sheetBName = "InputB"

       With ThisWorkbook.Names("inputData")
           If InStr(.RefersTo, sheetAName) > 0 Then
               .RefersTo = Replace(.RefersTo, sheetAName, sheetBName)
           Else
               .RefersTo = Replace(.RefersTo, sheetBName, sheetAName)
           End If
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

This routine will just change the definition of the named range to point either to the first or second input sheet. As a consequence, the helper sheet will show the data of the selected Input-Sheet. All your formulas itself stays unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, worked great!  But then immediately made me wonder....is the named range and the array and macro all necessary?  Why not have the 3rd Input "helper sheet" contain a direct cell-to-cell reference (=InputA!A1, =InputA!A2, etc) and then either by macro or just Find/Replace box, change all "A!" to "B!" just on the helper sheet.  Throughout the rest of the workbook, everything references the helper sheet, just as you suggested.  The end result is the same, right?  So does the array have a speed benefit or something?

Comment: No special benefit except that you do everything at once, so that the only thing you need to change is the range definition. I find this much easier than to have a different formula in every cell and the need to loop over all of them.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you could take the approach recommended by Damian and use a conditional in all relevant cells. The generic conditional would be

```
=IF(A1="InputA",FORMULA INPUTA,FORMULA INPUTB)
```

This formula makes `A1` the cell that decides which input to pull. This will make changing the around 350.000 output formulas in your workbook the bottleneck, the following macro takes care of changing all the formulas to conatin the conditional:

```
Sub changeFormulas()

Dim rng As Range, cll As Range

Set rng = shOutput.Range("A2:C10") 'Your relevant worksheet and range here

Dim aStr As String, bStr As String, formulaStr As String

aStr = "InputA"
bStr = "InputB"

For Each cll In rng
    If cll.HasFormula And InStr(1, cll.Formula, aStr, 1) Then
        formulaStr = Right(cll.Formula, Len(cll.Formula) - 1)
        cll.Formula = "=IF(A1=" & Chr(34) & aStr & Chr(34) & "," & formulaStr & "," & Replace(formulaStr, aStr, bStr) & ")" 'Change A1 to the reference most suited for your case
    End If
Next cll

End Sub
```

This might take a bit of time, since it has to access all the relevant cells one by one, but it will only have to run once.

To explain: This macro will go through all the cells in your range `rng` specified at the top. If a cell has a formula in it and the formula contains `"InputA"` it will change that formula to fit the generic conditional (with the cells own formula of course). `Chr(34)` is the quotation mark `"`, I find using `Chr(34)` more readable than multiple quotation marks `"""`, but that is just preference.